# Как задать отображение подсистемы в подсистеме?

Tags: 1с

1С Предприятие.
Имеется Подсистема "Автомобили". В ней ещё три: "В наличии", "С пробегом", "Актуальные". Так вот, когда открываю предприятие, то при клике на "Автомобили" у меня высвечиваются не названия подсистем ("В наличии", "С пробегом", "Актуальные"), а данные справочников, которые я добавлял во "В наличии" и в "С пробегом".
Как это исправить?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Включена панель текущих функций раздела. При такой настройке при втором клике по заголовку подсистемы откроется представление по подсистемам.
Чтобы отключить панель функций, необходимо зайти в главном меню "Вид" - "Настройка панелей" и перетащить панель в неиспользуемые панели.

Comment: Но я же тогда потом не смогу получить доступ к справочникам

Comment: Картинку к сожалению добавить не могу.
Если открыть настройки панелей твоего интерфейса, то первой будет "Панель инструментов" - ее не трогаем. 
Под ней "Панель функций текущего раздела". Если ее убрать, то при нажатии на подсистему сразу будет отображаться перечень объектов с разбивкой по подсистемам.